# error when run EmbeddedGraphDatabase

Tags: neo4j

I try run `EmbeddedGraphDatabase("/path/to/db")` in Java, but I get follow error:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@4abf053f' failed to initialize
```

**In neo4j.0.0.log:**

```
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
WARNING: WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Loaded neo4j tuning properties from conf/neo4j.properties
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start database.
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@19381960' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:281)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:163)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@19381960' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:259)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.jmx.impl.JmxKernelExtension@293bdd36' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:467)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.logging.Logging.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/neo4j/kernel/impl/util/StringLogger;
    at org.neo4j.management.impl.HotspotManagementSupport.getJMXServiceURL(HotspotManagementSupport.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.jmx.impl.JmxKernelExtension.init(JmxKernelExtension.java:57)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:467)
    ... 13 more
Jun 24, 2013 11:17:41 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Can you help me? TIA.

UPD. I use community version 1.9 stable.

UPD2. Neo4j-server worked fine, only embedded fail.

UPD3. This error appear only if I use tinkerpop:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.*;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.io.graphml.GraphMLReader;
```

UPD4. Java classpath:

```
2013-06-25 05:16:50.784+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Java classpath:
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-cypher-plugin-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/asm-3.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-jmx-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/conf/
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libatk-wrapper.so.0.0.18
2013-06-25 05:16:50.787+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-shell-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-multipart-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-kernel-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-algo-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/resources.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/blueprints-neo4j-graph-1.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.9-static-web.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/scala-library-2.10.0.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/neo4j-gremlin-plugin-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/rhino-1.7R3.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.788+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/mimepull-1.6.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-6.1.25.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.7.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/blueprints-core-1.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/janino-2.5.10.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jetty-util-6.1.25.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/antlr-2.7.7.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-lucene-index-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/netx.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.789+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/gremlin-groovy-1.5.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-udc-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/groovy-1.8.5.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/logback-classic-0.9.30.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/asm-util-3.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.790+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/server-api-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/pipes-1.0.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/jettison-1.3.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/asm-commons-3.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-1.9.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/asm-analysis-3.2.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/rrd4j-2.0.7.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/gremlin-java-1.5.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/logback-access-0.9.30.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/logback-core-0.9.30.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/jansi-1.5.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.791+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/a360-plugin-1.0.7-SNAPSHOT-bnull.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/system/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar
2013-06-25 05:16:50.792+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath + loader.0] file:/home/vinger4/neo4j/plugins/gremlin1.5/asm-tree-3.2.jar
```

Comment: in your graph.db/messages.log file there's a "Java classpath:" section... would you mind pasting that list for that run (possibly the last occurence of it) in your question?

Comment: looks like a version problem, or some logging lib not being on your classpath.

Comment: I am having the same error. But if I remove this dependency from my pom.xml, the error goes away. <groupId>com.tinkerpop.blueprints</groupId>
   <artifactId>blueprints-neo4j-graph</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.0</version>